# MongoDB ObjectID as primary key SQlite database

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I would like to use mongoDB's ObjectID as primary key in a SQlite database. I am thinking about storing it as a blob. It seems possible, but are there are any performance penalties compared to storing the hex value as a string with fixed length? Or is it even discouraged to choose string in this scenario?

Comment: What do MongoDB ObjectIDs look like?

Comment: @Shawn: It's an 12-byte value.